# Mixed content : This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mixed-content, baidu

I am developing a web app, which has map functionality. i download the map library using script tag in the index.html file. But now since it is the script tag, the map library is downloaded each and everytime I reload the browser. So inorder to cache it, I tried downloading it using $.ajax({url:"libraryURL" , cache:true}) . This downloads the library and cache it which is fine.
But the problem is I use https: to load my application, which works fine if I download the map library using script tag . Since now I changed to $.ajax, I see i am getting the below error.

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://baseurl ' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://online2.map.m/tile/'. This content should also be served over HTTPS

I am not clear why it is throwing error when I download the map script file using $.ajax, and the error doesn;t come up if I download it using script tag.

If I use $.ajax ,i see some request in http triggered which I don't knw why.And because of this i get the mixed content issue. Using script tag, don;t see this.

The url I use is exactly the same. Any idea ?

Please help...

Comment: As explain in your error, the content must be served over HTTPS, for security reason !

Comment: correct, but why the error only when I use $.ajax ? The map library internally is calling the http calls, which I don;t have any control

Comment: I don't why you don't have any problem by calling it by script tag ... maybe your security configuration of your browser ... but by the way you must call it in HTTPS.

Comment: yes the URL is anyhow in https only

Comment: AJAX is not cross-domain and is implemented within same domain. It is subject to Same Origin Policy

Comment: so how can this be fixed ?

Comment: "since it is the script tag, the map library is downloaded each and everytime I reload the browser" --> Are you certain about this? Doesn't the  script have any caching headers?

Comment: No..i didn't find any..Is there any available that you can help me with ?